# Converting char array into a string

Tags: java

I am making a hangman game. I have two char arrays and I need to check if they are equal.

One of them has letters and underscores: `char checkLetter[]`

The other one has only letters: `char currentWord[]`

Eventually, after the user has guessed all the words in the checkLetter[] array it will also consist of only letters. But I need to keep continually checking (in a boolean method) if the array into which they guess and their letters get stored, is the exact same as the word they are trying to guess.

If I could convert both of the arrays into strings then I could check them for equality. I am not experienced, and I don't know how to do this. Any help help would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string-java

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I disagree. Despite the title, the question is about checking equality of `char[]`s.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to convert them to strings at all. Use [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Would I just write: checkLetter.equals(currentWord) ?

Comment: No, read the linked javadocs. `Arrays.equals(checkLetter, currentWord)`.

Answer (score 3):

you can convert an char array into string using String's overloaded constructor which takes char[] array as argument.

```
char[] carr ;
String s = new String(carr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `new String(char[] value`)` to create String from [char array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 2):

Use the String-constructor:

```
String str = new String(yourCharArray);
```

However, that's useless; use `Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)` instead.

Comment: Would I just write: checkLetter.equals(currentWord) ?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to convert the array, but if you really want to then
try using `String word = currentWord.toString()` to convert the char array.