# String equality comparison failure in Java

Tags: java, string, jpa, oracle11g, ejb

I'm taking a one string value from an object in a object list.

```
transitionName = transitionList.get(m).getTransitionName().toString();
```

And another string value from an object retrieved by a EJB query.

```
changeItem = changeItemFacade.getChangeItem(changeGroupList.get(1));
char tempNewString[] = changeItem.getNewstring();
newString=new String(tempNewString);
```

Now this Char[] to String comparison is because the Oracle Table which contains the changeItem have defined the coloumn NewString as a CLOB.
And the ejb entity defines type of the variable 'NewString' as a Char[] array .
So i have to convert it to a string before doing the comparison.

The problem is that this if statement always returns false and doesn't get executed.

```
if(transitionName.equalsIgnoreCase(newString)){}
```

When i try to Log the values (Logger.Debug) , It perfectly show the two (equal) string values in the Server Instance log.

Is there something wrong with the way i convert the char[] array?

I tried changing the type of the entity class variable to String(and of course also the getter and setter methods) but doesn't work either.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string-java you are converting it the right way.

Comment: Try `trim()` on strings before comparing. Also, look for character encoding differences.

Comment: Thank you Singularity (Y) trim() method worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try trim() on strings before comparing. Also, look for character encoding differences. – Singularity