# How to convert char array back to string

Tags: java, arrays

There is a code which capitalize first word letter. However I wasn't able to find a method to convert char array back to String:

For example: "hello world" code transforms it to `["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]` I want to transform it back to "Hello World"

```
public class Solution
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();

        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
            if (chars[i] == ' '){
                chars[i + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(chars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String str = String.valueOf( chars );
```

or

```
String str = new String( chars );
```

Answer (score 0):

Two other remarks:

- In your approach, you should make sure, that the `[i+1]` element actually exists. A String like "Test ", ending with a space, would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your code.
- You should either close the Reader, or better: use a *try-with-resources* block like

`try( BufferedReder reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ) { 
    ... 
} catch( ... ) { 
    ... 
}`

which closes the Reader for you.