# Get String from Object which is a char array (NOT an Object[])

Tags: java

This is not a duplicate, please read the question and understand that I have an Object (**not** a char[], **not** an Object[], but **an Object**)

```
public String getStringFromObject(Object o){
  // What do I do here to get a String?  o is actually a char[]
}
```

I have a java Object that represents a character array:

I get passed an `Object cred` into a method

```
L.info("Credentials component type is {} and is array -> {}", 
       cred.getClass().getComponentType(), cred.getClass().isArray());
```

This prints: `Token's credentials are: [s, d, f] and type is [C`

How do I get this into a String?  I can't figure out how to cast the Object to any kind of `[]` array.  If it was `Object[]` to start with it would not be a problem.

Comment: `[C` means it's a `char[]` so cast to that. Then call the `String(char[])` constructor.

Comment: The output seems from a different log statement. Are you sure you posted the right one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a char array back to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string)

Comment: Why are you passing in an Object if it is a char[]? Why not just pass the character array? (I'm mainly asking this for my own selfish education). Is this for study?

Comment: Why you are doing it , when you can directly convert Character array to `String`? Help us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `char[]` and you want to convert it to a `String` simply use the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[]))

```
public String(char[] value)
```

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])):

> **Allocates a new String** so **that it represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the character array argument**. The contents of the character array are copied; subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the newly created string.

---

Note

If you have an `Object` that is a `char[]` here is what you have:

```
char[] x = ....;
Object objectIsACharArray = x;
String s = new String((char[]) x);
```

If the `Object` is not a `char[]` but is something that represent or hold a char array you need a custom code to convert it to a `String`.

Comment: You didn't understand the question.  I have an Object.

Comment: There is no `String` constructor that takes an `Object`. You can't just declare `x` as `Object` then call `new String(x)`, for this reason. Casting is an option here though, I believe.