# IF part not working. specificly when using && operator only else part is executing. || seems to work fine

Tags: java, if-statement, and-operator

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String a,b;
    a=jTextField1.getText();
    b=Arrays.toString(jPasswordField2.getPassword());
    if (a.equals("sam") && b.equals("hi")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login");
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
    }
}
```

only else part being executed, when using "or" operator if part works. seems to have error in "and" condition.

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` will return something different than `"hi"`, propably more like `"[\"hi\"]"`

Comment: The problem is much more likely to be with one or other of your fields than with the logic of the condition.

Comment: Problem in Arrays.toString

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a char array back to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string)

Comment: Tried using b=jPasswordField2.getPassword().toString();   .... Error remains the same

Comment: Use `new String(char[])` see the duplicate. Debugging would have show you the String

Comment: Thanks a Lot.... It worked.

Comment: You need to debug yourself first. Simply check the value where this failed. Using the debugger or simply by printing the values in the console

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString(new String[]{"hi"})` returns "[hi]".

So you should change your `if` to `if (a.equals("sam") && b.equals("[hi]"))` or your value of `b` to `b=jPasswordField2.getPassword()[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

getpassword method returns the password into brackets. return will be like this: [hi]. So you must use delete brackets. use a code like blow:

```
    b=b.substring(1,b.length()-1);
```

This code will delete the brackets in your password string.