# java: object as a return type

Tags: java, string

```
public class task1
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     StringClass s3 = new StringClass("ANYTHING");
     System.out.println("Lower Case: " + s3.toLowerCase());
  }
}

public class StringClass
{
  private char[] data;

  public StringClass(){
  }

  public StringClass(char[] input)
  {
    this.data = new char[input.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
      data[i] = input[i];
    }
  }

  public StringClass(String s)
  {
    this.data = s.toCharArray();
  }
  public StringClass toLowerCase()
  {
    int a;
    char ch;
    StringClass newStr = new StringClass();
    newStr.data = new char [data.length];
    newStr.data = this.data;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {

      if( data[i] >= 'a' && data[i] <= 'z')
      {
        newStr.data[i] = data[i];
      }
      else
      {
        a = (int) data[i] + 32;
        ch = (char) a;
        newStr.data[i] = ch;
      }
    }

    return newStr;
  }
}
```

So when I am calling this `s3.toLowerCase()` function in the main method it's returning a reference memory location. While I want to access the value which was converted into lower case. What I can't figure out is how I can get a String representation from the converted char array of the `StringClass` instance returned by the method `toLowerCase()`. The other thread doesn't explain how can I return the array from the `toString()` method.

Comment: you can add a getter in your StringClass class.

Comment: After the Edit the code and the text don't match anymore...

Comment: @Tom Oh that was a silly mistake on my part. I checked the IDE I used to format it now that you've mentioned it, and a part of the original code was not highlighted. Pure mistake. Not intentional. Sorry about that Shadow_Coder.

Comment: i can't figure how can i return the array from the toString().

Comment: You don't return an array, you return a String representation of the array. And that is researchable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Combining the information from the question previously linked as original and the information linked to in @Tom’s comment: add the following method override in your `StringClass` class:

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return new String(data);
  }
```

With this change your `task1` class outputs:

> Lower Case: anything

The `toString` method defines what should be printed instead of something like `StringClass@5c647e05`. `new String(data)` forms a new string from the chars in your `data` array.

`StringClass@5c647e05` is a string returned from `Object.toString`. `toString` can never return a char array since it is declared in the `Object` class, the parent of all Java classes, that it returns a `String`. So instead, as Tom said, we return a string representation of the array.

**Links**

- Question marked as original of this one: [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)
- Question linked by Tom: [How to convert a char array back to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655127/how-to-convert-a-char-array-back-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was this function and after creating this function I could call return object from the function and I would get the String inside of the object.

```
@Override
  public String toString()
  {
    String r = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      r += data[i];
    }
    return r;
  }
```