# Why toCharArray() and toString() method doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays

The **toCharArray()** in Java returns the Character Array and **Arrays.toString()** converts a array to string and **toString()** does same but why this below code doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"));

    char[] t = "abc".toCharArray();
    String t2 = Arrays.toString(t);

    if( ar.contains(t2)){
        System.out.println("contains"); // This line doesn't get executed
    }

    String t3 = t.toString();
    if( ar.contains(t3)){
        System.out.println("contains"); // This line doesn't get executed
    }

    if( ar.contains("abc")){
        System.out.println("contains"); // This line execute and prints on console
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you looked at the actual value or `ar`? I think that will make things obvious.

Comment: The code works, and does exactly what it should. `System.out.println(t2);` will tell you why it doesn't do what you think it should do.

Comment: "and toString() does same" not exactly. It is true that it also *returns* a String, but did you check what is the *content* of that String? If you want to create String from char[] you can use `new String(charArray)`.

Comment: Related: [How to convert a char array back to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7655127), [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402)

Comment: Also please try to avoid term "doesn't work". More info:  https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: When I printed out t2 it results out _[C@4c203ea1_, whereas when I print Arrays.toString(t), it prints _['a', 'b', 'c']_, so what toString is used for?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3615721). In short we use `toString()` to let methods like `println(someObject)` some *recipe* to generate string representation of any object passed as argument. So internally it will call `someObject.toString()` and will print that to console/file/wherever it was set to. So each time we design a class we can *override* `toString` method of it like `class Point{private int x, y; ... public toString(){ return "Point: x="+x+", y="+y;} ...}`.

Comment: But if we don't override that method its implementation will be inherited from closest ancestor which provides such implementation, which can also be an Object class where `toString` is implemented to `return getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`. Since arrays don't override it that is what you are seeing. So at `[C@4c203ea1` `[C` represents *one dimensional* `[` array of `char` (`C`) and after @ you see hashcode of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString()` called on a char array doesn't do the same.

When you write

```
String t3 = t.toString();
```

you said that you want to call `toString()` method from `Object.class`.
Because char array cannot have an overrided version of `toString()` that will do what you re expected, because it's an array of primitive type.
It works as expected, it returns you the string representation of a link to that particular char array in a heap.

`Arrays.toString(t)` returns you the string representation of an initial array.
In your case it will return `"[a, b, c]"`.
Then when you're trying to call `ar.contains(t2)` you re trying to find `"[a, b, c]"` string in your initial array which doesn't have it. It have 4 strings inside.
`"abc"`, `"def"`, `"ghi"`, `"jkl"`.
It doesn't contain the requested element (`"[a, b, c]" string`).

I would recommend you to debug your program. You will see which values are actually in your variables. It will give you a lot more understanding about this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString` returns `[a,b,c]` which is not equal to `abc`. See above answers why the other one didn't work.

Comment: I think, you mean to say."toString()" and "Arrays.toString()" does the same.

Comment: @AarravAgarwal "*"toString()" and "Arrays.toString()" does the same*" why? It is clearly not true and even example in your question disproves it. Did you actually check results of those methods?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `t.toString()` will return a String that is made up of all characters in the array `t`.  This is not the case, and nor does the language require it to be.

What you want is `String t3 = new String(t)`

Answer (score 0):

The code works exactly as expected. The ideal way to do this would be

```
String t2 = String.valueOf(t);
if(ar.contains(t2)){
    System.out.println("contains"); // This line execute and prints on console
}
```